# (Ajax) execute one ajax request after the code inside of succes of another ajax request (not inside of it )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two Ajax request the first one inside of each() and the second one outside of each. The problem is that the code inside the success of the first request is very important and should be executed before the second Ajax request.

After executing the code the first Ajax request is sent to the server but its success should only be executed after the second ajax request is executed.

order of execution:

```
first ajax
second ajax
success of first ajax
success of second ajax
```

Is there any way where the second ajax waits until the end of the success of the first one and then is executed?

```
$(document).on("change",
  ".jsQuestionType",
  function() {

    // alert("The dropdown has been changed.");

    var dropdownList = $(this);
    var optionTypeId = $(dropdownList).val();
    //get the  jsQuestionSection
    var question = $(dropdownList).parent().parent().parent();
    //get  the list of jsQuestionOptions 
    var questionOptions = $(dropdownList).parent().parent().parent().find(".jsQuestionOptions");

    // loop  in all  questionOptions  of the selected question

    $(questionOptions).each(function(i, e) {

      //alert($(e).find("input.jsInputName").attr("questionOptionsId"));
      var optionId = $(e).find("input.jsInputName").attr("questionOptionsId");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/api/QuestionOptions/" + optionId,
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function(data) {
          $(e).remove();

        }
      });
    });
    //End loop

    var questionId = $(question).find("input.jsInputName").attr("questionId");
    // if (questionOptions.length == 0) {
    // create   the new  option  using the  value sent by dropdown 

    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/QuestionOptions/" + optionTypeId + "/" + questionId,
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var d = data;
      }
    });

    //}

  });
```

Comment: You would need to move the 2nd AJAX call to the success of the first one, thus making the order of execution as this : 1st request => 1st response ==> 2nd request => 2nd response

Comment: I think your approach is flawed. First of all, it's a waste of resources to send multiple Ajax requests inside a loop. Just collect all the data, send it to the server in one go and process the data on the server. Second, you never can garantuee the outcome of the ajax calls in the order you want. You can do start 1, start 2, but if call 1 takes 10 seconds to respond and call 2 only 5, the order of success execution will be: 2, 1

Comment: i understand thanks for the informations i will change my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of the request promises in the loop and use `$.when` to call the ajax outside the loop after all the previous ones resolve if that's what you are trying to accomplish

```
var requests = $(questionOptions).map(function(i, e) {

  var optionId = $(e).find("input.jsInputName").attr("questionOptionsId");

  // return ajax promise
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/QuestionOptions/" + optionId,
    method: "DELETE",
    success: function(data) {
      $(e).remove();

    }
  });
}).get();

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(){
  // all the above requests completed
  // do next request

})
```